# How to work with types in a list correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I wrote a function that replaces all elements in the list with sets

```py
def get_set(arr):
  return list(map(lambda x: set(x),arr))
```

it works by example

```py
A=[(0, 3), (0, 4), (3, 4)]
A=get_set(A)
```

and we get

```py
A=[{0, 3}, {0, 4}, {3, 4}]
```

but if I use thif function for example

```py
B=[({0, 3}, {0, 4}), ({0, 3}, {3, 4}), ({0, 4}, {3, 4})]
get_set(B)
```

I get an error

```py
<ipython-input-50-10fd7735b9ce> in <lambda>(x)
      1 def get_set(arr):
----> 2   return list(map(lambda x: set(x),arr))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

How to fix my code and get?

```py
B=[{{0, 3}, {0, 4}}, {{0, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{0, 4}, {3, 4}}]
```

Comment: Just a note: there's no practical difference between `lambda x: set(x)` and `set`.

Comment: Short answer is you can't: sets are mutable, and therefore unhashable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the error tells you everything: elements like `set`, `dict`, `list`, etc, aren't hashable because they are mutable. That means you can't build a set from them.

But of course that's not the end of the story. You can meaningfully build a set of whatever you want, as long as you assign the meaning explicitly in a way that your object model allows. For example, you can create a mapping of unhashable types to functions that return a suitable alternative or wrapper:

```
type_map = {
    list: tuple,
    set: frozenset,
    dict: lambda x: tuple(x.items()),
    bytearray: bytes,
}
```

If course a `dict` is only completely useful if you plan to do type checking of the form `type(x) == y` rather than using the more idiomatic `isinstance`. However, even in you latter case, `dict` makes for a nice container of pairs.

A more general solution might be something like

```
def wrap_type(x):
    """
    Attempt to turn `x` into a hashable type using registry in `type_map`.

    The result is not guaranteed to be hashable.
    """
    for t, w in type_map.items():
        if isinstance(x, t):
            return w(x)
    return x

def transform_set(i):
    return set(wrap_type(x) for x in i)

def get_set(i):
    return list(map(transform_set, i))
```

This implementation has (at least) one deficiency: `wrap_type` is not recursive. It might correctly transform all your lists to tuples, but that won't make the result hashable if any of the elements aren't hashable. The problem only applies to certain types, like `list`, `dict`, and even `tuple`, but not `bytearray` or `set`.

You can avoid this by implementing `type_map` to include recursion:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence, Mapping, Set

def wrap_seq(s):
    return tuple(wrap_type(x) for x in s)

def wrap_map(m):
    return tuple((k, wrap_type(v)) for k, v in m.items())

type_map = {
    Sequence: wrap_seq,
    Set: frozenset,
    Mapping: warp_map,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every element in B is tuple of sets. You can use a [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) which is hashable.
And so every element can be hashable and it can be converted to a set.

```
def get_set(arr):
  return list(map(set, arr))

B=[
  (frozenset([0, 3]), frozenset([0, 4])),  
  (frozenset([0, 3]), frozenset([3, 4])), 
  (frozenset([0, 4]), frozenset([3, 4]))  
 ]
B=get_set(B)
print(B)
```

OUTPUT

```
[set([frozenset([0, 4]), frozenset([0, 3])]), set([frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([0, 3])]), set([frozenset([3, 4]), frozenset([0, 4])])]
```

Answer (score 0):

def get_set(arr):
return list(map(lambda x: set(x),arr))
it works by example

A=[(0, 3), (0, 4), (3, 4)]
A=get_set(A)
and we get

A=[{0, 3}, {0, 4}, {3, 4}]
but if I use thif function for example

B=[({0, 3}, {0, 4}), ({0, 3}, {3, 4}), ({0, 4}, {3, 4})]
get_set(B)
I get an error

in (x)
1 def get_set(arr):
----> 2   return list(map(lambda x: set(x),arr))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'